# Programming help for Verilog beginner. Debugging in ISE

Tags: verilog

I have experience in VHDL and SystemC, and now I'm training to learn Verilog, but I'm having trouble getting started.

I'm currently trying to make a 8 bit adder.

```
module alu(
input [7:0] a,
input [7:0] b,
input clk,
input op,
output reg [7:0] out,
output reg overflow
);

integer myA;
integer myB;

always @(negedge clk)
begin
myA = a;
myB = b;
overflow = 0;

if (op == 0) begin
    //Subtract
    out = myA - myB;
    if (myA - myB <0) begin
        overflow = 1;
    end
end 
else begin
    //Add
    out = myA + myB;
    if (myA + myB  > 255) begin
        overflow = 1;
        end
    end

end

endmodule
```

But in testing it doesn't work properly.

I used ISE to generate a test bench, and since I don't know how to setup a clock, I set it up manually:

```
// Add stimulus here
    a = 255;
    b = 45;
    clk = 1;
    op = 1;
    #100
    clk = 0;

    // Add stimulus here
    a = 0;
    b = 255;
    clk = 1;
    op = 1;
    #100
    clk = 0;

    // Add stimulus here
    a = 255;
    b = 0;
    clk = 1;
    op = 0;
    #100
    clk = 0;

    // Add stimulus here
    a = 90;
    b = 45;
    clk = 1;
    op = 1;
    #100
    clk = 0;
```

The last instruction, 45+90 gives me the correct result, but every other result gives me 0.

I've tried several variations of the main if, but there always errors in the output.

```
if (op == 0) begin
  out = a + b;
if (myA-myB <0) begin
  //overflow
  out = 7;
end
end else begin
  out = a-b;
   if (myA+myB>255) begin
    //overflow
    out = 8;
   end
end
```

Here's the full test bench code. Edited to include #100 between clk = 0 and clk = 1.

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module a;

// Inputs
reg [7:0] a;
reg [7:0] b;
reg clk;
reg op;

// Outputs
wire [7:0] out;

// Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
alu uut (
    .a(a), 
    .b(b), 
    .clk(clk), 
    .op(op),
    .out(out)
);

initial begin
    // Initialize Inputs
    a = 0;
    b = 0;
    clk = 0;
    op = 0;

    // Wait 100 ns for global reset to finish
    #100;

    // Add stimulus here
    a = 55;
    b = 45;
    clk = 1;
    op = 1;
    #100
    clk = 0;
    #100

    // Add stimulus here
    a = 255;
    b = 45;
    clk = 1;
    op = 1;
    #100
    clk = 0;
    #100

    // Add stimulus here
    a = 0;
    b = 255;
    clk = 1;
    op = 1;
    #100
    clk = 0;
    #100

    // Add stimulus here
    a = 255;
    b = 0;
    clk = 1;
    op = 0;
    #100
    clk = 0;
    #100

    // Add stimulus here
    a = 90;
    b = 45;
    clk = 1;
    op = 1;
    #100
    clk = 0;
    #100
end

endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

`#X` in Verilog means "delay X time steps before continuing". So in your code

```
#100
clk = 0;

// Add stimulus here
a = 255;
b = 0;
clk = 1;
```

there's no delay between the clock going low and going high again, which might be your problem. Try adding a `#100` somewhere between `clk = 0;` and `clk = 1;`

Comment: Also, it's good practice use a non-blocking assignment (`<=`) in a clocked `always` block (like your `alu`) instead of a blocking assignment (`=`).

Comment: thanks. I was confused when to use = vs <=. Verilog took =, so I just went with it

Answer (score 0):

Just a tip. I think in most cases the clock is created in an always block and then the inputs are changed in another initial block so

```
always begin
  #5 clk = ~ clk; // here the clock period is 10
end

initial begin
  clk = 0;
  a = 255;
  b = 45;
  op = 1;

  #10;

  a = 90;
  b = 45;
  op = 1;     
end
```